# Authorization & Capture doable in paypal sdk for android?

Tags: android, paypal, payment

I've been looking for ways to implement Authorization & Capture in android using paypal sdk. I only found it doable using the website payment standard. Is it doable in the mobile platform as well by using the paypal sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement authorization and capture using the Mobile Express Checkout Library of paypal found [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index).